# Unix Script to remove last seven characters from a variable

Tags: unix, sh

Need to remove the last seven characters from a variable.

For example if my variable string is

```
COLUMN_NAME||','||
```

then it should output `COLUMN_NAME`

I have tried the below but last pipe symbol only getting removed

```
var=$(lastline%|)
var=$(lastline%|*)
```

Result : `COLUMN_NAME||','|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the last 7 characters:

```
$ var="COLUMN_NAME||','||"
$ echo "${var%???????}"
COLUMN_NAME
```

To remove everything after the *first* pipe:

```
$ echo "${var%%|*}"
COLUMN_NAME
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion
and https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching

Comment: `?` seems to be the forgotten glob wildcard character. Let's all give it a hug.

Comment: @fedorqui I see what you did there ;)

Answer (score 2):

The old school way

```
echo "COLUMN_NAME||','||" | rev|cut -c 8-|rev
```

So you are just reversing the string, deleting first `7` characters and again reversing the string.

Use the `$variable` with echo to do the same.

You can also use `awk` like below which would be faster.

```
awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-7)}'
```

Example:

```
$ export variable1="COLUMN_NAME||','||"
$ echo $variable1|rev|cut -c 8-|rev
COLUMN_NAME
$ echo $variable1|awk '{print substr($0, 1, length($0)-7)}'
COLUMN_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two `%` to strip the longest match:

```
$ r="COLUMN_NAME||','||"
$ echo ${r%%|*}
COLUMN_NAME
```

As BashFAQ says in [Removing part of a string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string):

> `%` means "remove the shortest possible match from the end of the
>   variable's contents".
>
> `%%` means "remove the longest possible match from the end of the
>   variable's contents".

Answer (score 0):

You could find the length of your string/s and index from that point:

```
str1="1234567890foobar";
strlen=${#str1};

str2=${str1:0:$strlen-7};
echo $str2;
```